# Im using Advanced custom fields, but how can I let my javascript loop through rows?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function validateform() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('textareabox');
  var word = 'get-help get-service';
  var word2 = "get-service -?";

  var textValue = textarea.value.toLowerCase();
  if (textValue.indexOf(word) != -1) {
    document.getElementById("correcto").innerHTML = "NAME<br>\r\n    Get-Service<br>\r\n\r\nSYNTAX\r\n    Get-Service [[-Name] <string[]>] [-ComputerName <string[]>] [-DependentSe\r\n    <string[]>] [-Exclude <string[]>]  [<CommonParameters>]<br>\r\n<br>\r\n    Get-Service -DisplayName <string[]> [-ComputerName <string[]>] [-Dependen\r\n    <string[]>] [-Exclude <string[]>]  [<CommonParameters>]<br>\r\n<br>\r\n    Get-Service [-ComputerName <string[]>] [-DependentServices] [-RequiredSer\r\n    <string[]>] [-InputObject <ServiceController[]>]  [<CommonParameters>]<br>";
    return true;
      } 
        if (textValue.indexOf(word2) != -1) {
    document.getElementById("correcto").innerHTML = "NAME<br>\r\n    Get-Service<br>\r\n\r\nSYNTAX\r\n    Get-Service [[-Name] <string[]>] [-ComputerName <string[]>] [-DependentSe\r\n    <string[]>] [-Exclude <string[]>]  [<CommonParameters>]<br>\r\n<br>\r\n    Get-Service -DisplayName <string[]> [-ComputerName <string[]>] [-Dependen\r\n    <string[]>] [-Exclude <string[]>]  [<CommonParameters>]<br>\r\n<br>\r\n    Get-Service [-ComputerName <string[]>] [-DependentServices] [-RequiredSer\r\n    <string[]>] [-InputObject <ServiceController[]>]  [<CommonParameters>]<br>";
    return true;

        }  else {
    document.getElementById("incorrecto").innerHTML = 'Incorrect!';
  }
}
</script>
```

The scripts loop through 2 custom fields:

- answer1
- answer2

if the answer is not correct it will say incorrect!

But with this script I can only have 2 answers, I change this by adding an extra answer button, answer3 or answer4 but this is not desirable.

I rather have the script to loop through every row in answer1:

Answer1:

```
this is the answer
```

but this could also be the answer

```
this aswell
```

And if there are no more rows it says Incorrect!
this way I can add way more answers.

But I don't know where to start for this,  can only create extra "If"'s
Im calling the custom field in the PHP from, so how does the javascript know it are extra's rows and not a complete answer 4 lines? How can I let javascript loop through the rows.

Could someone help me on my way?

Comment: Can you add it in a snippet or add HTML also.

Comment: That's only a textarea box. everything works, but I want it to check the rows..